# What is Mountain Pass theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, bounded-variation

The title says it all, what is mountain pass theorem, how does it work is variational problems with doubly differential constraint?

Comment: The first hit on google is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem). Have you looked at it?

Comment: "how does it work is variational problems with doubly differential constraint?" there is nothing about this there!

Comment: Could you please specify (by editing the post) what you mean by a doubly differential constraint? Why do you think the mountain pass theorem should apply in the presence of such a constraint?

Comment: i have a functional that corresponds to the position of discrete breather(DB) in periodic hamiltonian lattice with nonlinear interaction potential between them, the solution of the hamiltonian that corresponds with an  existence of DB is the one for which the action is constant and the solution is non-trivial, this action is twice differentiable is first and second derrivatives exist. the paper i am studying used mountain pass theorem to prove the existence of DB.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer your question. I would recommend putting some more detail into the question so that someone better equipped to answer it has more to work with. In particular, you should include a reference to the paper you are reading.

Comment: which paper are you studying?